# Hibernate add custom prefix to the catalogs

Tags: java, database, hibernate, configuration, schema

I'm using Hibernate 4.3.6 and I need to add custom prefix to my catalogs depending on the environment. I used to do this code in version 4.2.3

```
private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
    try {
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.configure("db.cfg.xml");
        config.buildMappings();

        ServiceRegistry registry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                .applySettings(config.getProperties())
                .build();

        if (prefix != null && !prefix.isEmpty()) {
            Iterator<Table> iterator = config.getTableMappings();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                Table table = (Table) iterator.next();
                table.setCatalog(prefix + table.getCatalog());
            }
        }
        //return new AnnotationConfiguration().buildSessionFactory(registry);
        SessionFactory factory = config.buildSessionFactory(registry);
        return factory;
    }
    catch (Throwable ex) {
        // Make sure you log the exception, as it might be swallowed
        System.err.println(ex);
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }
}
```

But now it errors out on

```
config.buildSessionFactory(registry);

java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at db.DatabaseEngine.buildSessionFactory(DatabaseEngine.java:110)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1456)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1844)
at db.DatabaseEngine.buildSessionFactory(DatabaseEngine.java:104)
... 26 more
```

Is there such thing like ImprovedNamingStrategy but for catalogs?

Comment: Could you provide a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) or provide all sources (class and configuration)? That `NullPointerException` is occurring at an odd place for the version 4.3.6 Configuration class. Also, what vendor and version of Java are you using?

Comment: If I rem out the portion of code where I add prefix it will not crash. The java vesion is 1.7 and its sun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you create an orm.xml, you can load it using the following code:

```
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.configure("db.cfg.xml");
config.addResource("orm.xml"); // Load these files in any order
config.buildMappings();
```

See Vlad's answer for how to create an orm.xml file.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Hibernate Annotation docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#d0e3578) the orm.xml XML settings can override the annotation configs:

```
<entity-mappings 
  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm orm_2_0.xsd"
  version="2.0">

    <persistence-unit-metadata>
        <persistence-unit-defaults>
            <schema>${db.schema}</schema>
            <catalog>${db.catalog}</catalog>
        </persistence-unit-defaults>
    </persistence-unit-metadata>

    <entity class="package.YourEntity1">        
        <table name="YOUR_TABLE_1" catalog="${specific_catalog1}"/>       
    </entity>

    <entity class="package.YourEntity2">        
        <table name="YOUR_TABLE_2" catalog="${specific_catalog2}"/>       
    </entity>
```

The schema/catalog variables can be replaced by Maven based on a specific profile that you run prior to building. That works for both the default catalog and for specific entity catalog definitions.

Comment: What if I have multiple different catalogs on different java files?

Comment: In that case you can override the Java annotation table definitions with XML entity declarations that are filtered by Maven on build time like in the example I gave you.

Comment: Any idea how to do this at service start-up time (Using a Tomcat 7 server) instead of at Maven build time.  Planning on distributing the JAR's, not building on client machines via Maven.

Comment: I don't think Hibernate supports runtime variable substitution. You have to prepare multiple environment config files and supply the right ones when your app bootstraps. It's a runtime design thing. It's not trivial yet doable.

Comment: The documentation Vlad added is out of date (Hibernate 3.5). The most recent documentation that exists I could find addressing this issue is [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/hem/en-US/html_single/) (Hibernate 4.0). To use it you need to use the HibernateEntityManager, which is a wrapper around the SessionFactory that conforms to JPA specifications. Is there a way to do this with a SessionFactory?

Comment: You can use hbm files instead. Xml config take precedence.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't be more simpler loading configuration file per environment, I mean (depends of the env)

```
config.configure("db.cfg-env1.xml");
```

or

```
config.configure("db.cfg-env2.xml");
```

and there set the proper catalog in the jdbc connection url ?

Example close to implementation (thx serge for letting me know :))

```
config.configure(String.format("db.cfg-%s.xml"), env);
```

Comment: So the second configure will not replace the first one and instead accumulate?

Comment: My first impression is that this would increase require multiple datasources and multiple session factories, which could violate the original poster's constraints.